# php для отдельного домена на сервере

Tags: php

на сервере установлен php 5.6.30, есть некоторые проекты, мне надо залить свои изменения, но они работают ток с php 7, там laravel, сервер на vesta, можно сделать атк чтобы только мой домен работал под php 7? наверняка что то в апаче следует сделать )

Comment: Нужно просто установить пхп 7, в апаче ничего делать не надо

Comment: Под nginx - поставить докер контейнер с php7 php-fpm или компилировать в другую директорию. Под апач - думаю можно скомпилировать нужный php и модуль под апач в другой директории. С докером можно поднимать контейнер с nginx + php хоть на каждый проект, только надо будет решить как 80 порт разделить на всех - еще один nginx пробрасывающий запросы дальше.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно гуглить в сторону php-fpm 
Там есть возможность хоть для каждой папки ставить разный php

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]